# how to use session to navigate between pages

Tags: php

Can we write something like this  to make this code actually functional.

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
        header("Location: profile.php");
    } 
    else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried, if it works? If it doesn't, that you can't, if it does, then you can.

Comment: the code is valid from a syntax standpoint. From a functional standpoint we cannot say. It depends on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Is that you mentioning that the code doesn't work?
You'd need to use session_start() first for the script to access session variables..

Comment: i have added on every page. And session is working fine,but after writing this code,page just goes blank.

Comment: Do you have any content in profile.php? Maybe share the code in it, You could also try debugging by putting different echo outputs for each conditional to check if they work.

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors? HTTP redirection specified in header won't work after any output has been done.

Comment: Just a blank page opens. Its header is right,but nothing is displaying on the screen.

Comment: Maybe it's really redirecting to the new page (profile.php or index.php), you could use echo to check which condition its executing. Do you have the session initiated in them too, It'd be better if you can share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `session_start();` at the top of every pages. If not, cannot be.

Example:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
        header("Location: profile.php");
    } 
    else {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: i have added session_start();

Comment: session is working perfectly,after writing this code,then page goes blank.

Comment: According your code, if have session, go to profile.php page. Did you write something on profile.php page? May be u should write echo "hello"; 
Reference link --> http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php